# Write-host, Issues with looping, how to get a summary string?

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I'm working on getting a script of mine to output bits of info to the screen when it's ran. I've got some foreach/if loops that don't seem to be catching correctly.  Say I've got something like:

```
$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" | 
    where {$_.name -replace 'Report to ' -in $name} | 
    select name, samaccountname


Foreach ($manager in ($managers.SamAccountName)) { 

if ($manager -notin (($ReportsTo.Name) -replace 'Report to ')) { 
    new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou
    write-host = "New group for " + $manager + " has been created."
    
} else {
    write-host = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists."
    
}
```

As this is written it write to the screen on each iteration whether the new group is created or already exists. It does this regardless of if the group actually exists or not. Say a group named 'Report to Sam.Walton' exists in the `-path $ou` and the script is ran.. according to the group timestamps the group is not recreated, but the loop still prints that a New groups for $manager was created.
If I step into this debugging in the ISE, I can never get $ReportsTo to print a value.  So maybe that line is just wrong.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include output for the `select name, samaccountname` in the first statement, include output for `$managers`, so that we can follow your script a bit better? Also, try assigning the result of `New-ADGroup` to a variable and do a `Write-Host` on that - it's possible that the group is not being created, but there's no error.

Comment: Small nitpick - try ```write-host "New group for '$manager' has been created."``` instead - the ```=``` is treated as part of the output and not an assignment, and the same for the ```+``` - it's part of the output not a string concatenation the way you've done it. *And* if you wrap the ```$manager``` value in visible delimiters you can see much easier if there's a leading / trailing space in the variable value, which might be frustrating the ```if``` condition.

Comment: For example, ```write-host = "New group for " + $manager + "has been created."``` outputs ```= New group for  + Sam.Walton + has been created.```, whereas ```write-host "New group for '$manager' has been created."``` outputs ```New group for 'Sam.Walton' has been created.```

Comment: Mclayton, thanks for the pointers on the write-host lines.. I always assumed you needed an = sign.

Answer (score 1):

IF `$name` is an array of SamAccountNames (just the strings, not objects), then why not clean up the `$ReportsTo` array like this:

```
$ReportsTo = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $ou Filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" | 
    Where-Object {($_.Name -replace 'Report to ') -in $name} | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'name'; Expression = {$_.Name -replace 'Report to '}}, 
                  samaccountname
```

Then your test can be simplified to:

```
if ($manager -notin ($ReportsTo.Name)) {..}
```

Please tell us what exactly `$name` contains.

Comment: Theo, Thanks again for the input. So the way the $reportsto string is formatted is from another StackOverflow suggestion. I ended up finding a solution on my own that involved commenting the 'where=object' line out. And using a bit of the syntax you gave me on my last posting.  Looky here:

Comment: `Foreach ($manager in ($managers.SamAccountName)) { 
    $reportsto = $reportsto -replace ("Report to ","")
    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou
        $LogLine = "New group for " + $manager + " has been created."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    } else {
        $LogLine = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }`